# Limited Object type in .NET

Tags: .net, oop

Let's have a library of objects `Person`, `Cat`, `Dog`, `Pencil` and `Byke`.

Let's give to `Person` a `FavoriteThing` member, that can be of any of listed types.

Let's imagine that we have to save the Person's state using a serialization, so we make all of listed objects as `Serializable`.

How do we now protect the Person from "injecting" him a "FavoriteThing" like `Cobra` class, that does not comply the requirements (to be Serializable, or others, like to be inoffensive :).

Comment: How do you determine what objects are allowed, and which are not allowed. And how will the Person *inject* a different object?

Comment: @astander: this is my question. Say, I have a list of allowed types, and I should check this in the FavoriteThing member in a way... preferable that the detection be in compile time that in runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to write a `FavoriteThing` type which acts as a [tagged union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union). In other words, it has a property for each type (person, cat etc) but enforces that it only contains one value at a time. You may not explicitly need a tag field if these are all reference types; just make sure that only one of your strongly-typed fields is non-null at a time. You will need to provide a way of determining *which* type has a value though.

Another option is to make all of those types implement a common interface - but that *may* not be an appropriate design, if those types shouldn't really know about the "favorite" concept.

It's hard to be more concrete without knowing what you'd want to do with the favorite thing...

Comment: say, the first restriction to a favoriteThing to be a Serializable class.

Comment: @serhio - there is no compiler-based way of doing that for `[Serializable]`. You *could* perhaps do it for `ISerializable`, but then you have to do a lot of work yourself. Plus, you might not *want* to use `BinaryFormatter`

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure exactly what you want to achieve, but if you in some way want to be able to define what types should be allowed to be assigned to `FavoriteThing`, you could create an empty interface (let's call it `IFavorable`), and declare `FavoriteThing` as being of that type;

```
public interface IFavorable { }

class Person
{
    public IFavorable FavoriteThing { get; set; }
}
```

Then you make the allowed types "implement" this interface:

```
class Dog : IFavorable
{
    // ...
}
```

That would work, though I am not a huge fan of such "meta interfaces" myself...

Comment: this is, surely, a solution :) empty interface.

Comment: @serhio: It depends on whether the types should logically "know" about the favoriting concept. It also depends on whether you can change all the favoritable types... for example, this isn't going to help if you ever want to be able to make a "String" a favorite thing.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: ya ya. have reason.

Comment: @serhio: I have no idea what "have reason" means in the context of my comment.

Comment: it just means that you have reason :)  a .NET framework object can't implement an IFavoriteThing

Answer (score 1):

Best on your related recent post, this relates to a `List<object>`, yes?

In this case, I wouldn't use `object` - I'd use a common base-class:

```
[Serializable]
public class FavoriteThing {} // this is probably a bad name...

[Serializable]
public class Dog : FavoriteThing {}

[Serializable]
public class Pencil : FavoriteThing {}
```

(and use a `List<FavoriteThing>` instead of `List<object>`)

Note that this **doesn't** enforce the `[Serializable]` - no compiler check can do that; but it *does* keep it to sane values - i.e. not (ranadomly) a `HttpWebRequest`

Additionally, multiple serializers will work happily with a base-class model, that **won't** work with random `object`s - for example `DataContractSerializer`, `XmlSerializer`, etc. Normally I prefer encapsulation over inheritance, but for serialization / DTO, a base-class is *usually* the simplest option.

Comment: unfortunately, I can't define a FavoriteThing base class, because I should inherit `Dog` and `Cat` from `Animal`, and `Byke` from `TransportUnit`

Comment: Indeed; but consider: your DTO model (for serialization) is not *necessarily* the same object-model as your OOP model... it *sometimes* is, but when it starts to get complex: split the two. You'll save a lot of pain.